# How to pass multiple parameter to a function or query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What i want is to fetch all those customer's profile whose country in address is india.

I am having two tables `customers` and `address`. '`customers`' table have `address_ID` and in `address` table i am having the `country_ID`.

I have tried so far is this :

On ajax call i get this controller's function:

```
function listCustomerByCountry(){
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_REQUEST['id']!=null)
{       $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        //print_r($id);

         $cid=$this->report_model->getAddressidByCountryid($id);

        foreach($cid as $rs)
        {
            $addid = $rs['addressId'];  
            print_r($addid);
            $result=$this->report_model->get_customer_by_addressId($addid);
            print_r($result);
        }

         //var_dump($cid);
         //die();
            $result=$this->report_model->get_customer_by_addressId($addid);
            print_r($result);


}else
{
        $result=$this->report_model->get_customer_by_addressId();
}
echo'<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" ><thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Customer Address</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th><th>Plan Type</th><th>Application Status</th><th>View</th><th>Edit</th><th>Ticket</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach ($result as $customers){
$status = unserialize (STATUS);
$statusDb = $customers['applicationStatus'];

        $val='<tr class="gradeX"><td>'.$customers['customerVisibleId'].'</td>';
        $val.='<td><a href="'.base_url("customer/profile/".$customers['customerId']).'">'.$customers['customerName'].'</td>';
        $val.='<td>'.$customers['customerAddress'].'</td>';
        $val.='<td>'.$customers['phnoMobile'].'</td>';
        $val.='<td>'.$customers['email1' ].'</td>';
        $val.='<td>'.$customers['planId'].'</td>';
        $val.='<td>'.($status[$statusDb]).'</td>';
        $val.='<td><a href="'. base_url("customer/view/".$customers['customerId']).'"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></td>';
        $val.='<td><a href="'.base_url("customer/edit/".$customers['customerId']).'"><img src="'.base_url().'assets/img/edit.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></td>';
        $val.='<td><a href="'.base_url("customer/ticketid/".$customers['customerId']).'"><i class="fa fa-text-width"></i></a></td>';               
        $val.= '</tr>';
        echo $val;

}
echo '</tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>';
die();
```

}

and in model i am fetching `country_ID` from `address` table based on the dropdown selection and then the customer's profile data from `customers` table based on the `address_ID`.

Model:

```
    public function getAddressidByCountryid($id){
$query = $this->db->get_where('address', array('country' => $id));
$row=$query->result_array();
return $row;

}

public function get_customer_by_addressId($id)
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('customerAddress' => $id));
print_r($id);
die();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Problem is i am only getting the last address_ID and last customerID when fetch from the second function `get_customer_by_addressId`

What wrong i am doing? do the controller function not passing all the addres_IDs?

**Table Structure**

```
Table Customers
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | addressID |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | demo  |        12 |
|  2 | test  |        13 |
|  3 | demo1 |        14 |
|  4 | demo2 |        15 |
+----+-------+-----------+

Table address:

+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----+
| addressID | countryID | stateID          | cityID |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----+
|        12 |         1 |                1 |   1 |
|        13 |         1 |                1 |   1 |
|        14 |         1 |                1 |   1 |
|        15 |         2 |                2 |   2 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----+
```

Result Table

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | addressID |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | demo  |        12 |
|  2 | test  |        13 |
|  3 | demo1 |        14 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Now i want all the customr's data whose countryID is 1

Comment: You have typo within your query. I'm wondering of even how could you get even a single value. You have an error within your **if** condition you have an else within it

Comment: @NarendraSisodia yeah i edited, but the problem is same

Comment: you fetching country_ID from address $query = $this->db->get_where('address', array('country_ID' => $id));

Comment: What you were suppose to get within `$addid` an array it seems you are getting the last value of id you have to place `$result=$this->report_model->get_customer_by_addressId($addid);` within foreach. Or can you please udpate your question with updated result

Comment: @saty:that is what i suppose fetch, the country_ID

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i updated my controller code, now it is fetching all the rows whose country_ID is 1, but how to display it now in the same for each?

Comment: Can you update your question with table structure with your expected answer so there might be possible solution to get values using join query

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i explaned with table structure, i hope now you got what result i want, pls check

Comment: @Anonymus I have posted my answer check if it works as you desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm updating your code as below.

**Controller**

```
$result = $this->report_model->getAddressidByCountryid($id);
print_r($result);
```

and within your model

```
public function getAddressidByCountryid($id){
  $this->db->select('c.*');
  $this->db->from('Customers c');
  $this->db->join('address a','c.addressID = a.addressID','left');
  $this->db->where('a.countryID',$id);
  $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
  return $result;
}
```